# Importing/exporting animation into Blender using Collada

Tags: animation, export, import, collada

Have an issue with importing/exporting animation into Blender using Collada.

Steps taken:

- Export character from Mixamo with simple walk cycle in .dae format
- Import file into Blender.

The result is the mesh getting distorted.
https://imgur.com/a/24lXGW0

Stuff I've done:

- Quaternion rotation
- Changed to blender render (apparently, cycles was giving an issue)
- Clear scale, rotation, normals, etc
- Zero coordinates
- Not use better collada (didn't work trying to use it)
- Baking animations using recommended settings
- Default settings from export and every other setting
- Exporting the animation/skeleton purely as .dae
- Pretty much whatever I could find online, blender stack exchange forums/etc

Comment: Nvm, turns out it's a collada bug. Sent a bug report to the devs.
https://developer.blender.org/T56516

Comment: I'm having the exact same bug with the same set of meshes that you were using. I saw in the bug that theoretically it was already fixed, but it seems that the bug is still happening using latest blender release. Was the bug ever fixed?